# Count vowels and even in text file using C++

Tags: c++, file-handling

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    set<char> vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
    string filename("carry.txt");
    vector<char> bytes;
    char byte = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int vowelsCount = 0;
    ifstream input_file(filename.c_str());
    if(!input_file.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Could not open the file - '" << filename << "'" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    while(input_file.get(byte)) {
        bytes.push_back(byte);
    }
    for(const auto& i : bytes) {
        if(i % 2 == 0) {
            count++;
        }
        if(find(vowels.begin(), vowels.end(), byte) != vowels.end()) {
            vowelsCount++;
        }
    }
    cout << "Number of vowels are:" << vowelsCount << endl;
    cout << "Number of Evens are:" << count << endl;
    input_file.close();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Counting vowels and even number In a text file but vowelcount is not working also even count is working but showing count as 5 but the data in the file is 123454Mohsin maybe it is also counting ascii value of characters

Comment: The even numbers are digits? The even digit characters are the characters `'0'`, `'2'`, `'4'`, `'6'`, `'8'`. Please, note that  `'0'` as well as `0` can be considered as integral values but `'0'` is different from `0`. (Assuming ASCII encoding, e.g. `'0' == 48`.)

Comment: What should the program produce with a file containing `123454Mohsin`?

Comment: Please don't cut out parts of your program so that it doesn't compile when you ask questions. I fixed the missing parts this time though.

Comment: The program produces :   Number of vowels are:0
Number of Evens are:5

Answer (score 1):

Your find statement is referencing `byte` when you probably meant to reference `i`.  But Your `find` statement isn't the most efficient way to search a `set`  - invoke the `find` method directly off the set object.  And your counting of even numbers is evaluating `i` as it's ordinal ascii value regardless if it's an actual number between 0-9.

Create another set for even numbers (as chars):

```
set<char> evens = {'0', '2', '4', '6', '8'};
```

Then instead of this:

```
for(const auto& i : bytes) {
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
        count++;
    }
    if(find(vowels.begin(), vowels.end(), byte) != vowels.end()) {
        vowelsCount++;
    }
}
```

This:

```
for (char i : bytes) {
    if (evens.find(i) != evens.end()) {
        count++;
    }
    else if (vowels.find(i) != vowels.end()) {
        vowelsCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: if I have some other evens apart from 0 2 4 6 8 this program will again give wrong input isn't?

Comment: What's an `even` ?  Please define that.  I just assumed you meant a digit that is considered an even number.

Comment: `123454Mohsin` has 3 even numbers (2,4,and4) and 2 vowels: o and i.  Right?

Comment: yes but it is showing wrong output

Comment: I am not sure about it but 123454Mohsin should print 3 evens but it is printing 5 so that means it is also applying condition on characters ASCII

Comment: I had a typo in my answer, which I just corrected. Perhaps that will help.

Comment: No just for a moment leave that ASCII or character position simply if your digits in a file NUMERIC so how will you count them

Answer (score 1):

Your check for being "even" is applied to the character's numeric code (ASCII code in typical cases) - which is not the same as checking for even-number characters. The even-number characters are '0','2',...'8', whose [ASCII values](https://www.asciitable.com/) are 48, 50,...,56. Half of the alphabet has even ASCII values - but obviously you shouldn't count those.

Also, you need to make it clear you're counting even-number *characters*. If you want to count even *numbers* appearing in your input, you'd need to look at sequences of characters. And interpret them together.

Comment: Good catch. I just asked myself the "What if he really meant numbers?" and I just assumed digits...

Comment: I want to count the number not the character let suppose I have file with 123454Mohsin so it should print 3 because there are three evens in the file but as I know I am reading it character by character how should I convert it to number first and then count ? Also in other case of vowels it is not working output of vowel count is zero

Comment: @MohsinMehmood: It seems you want to count the numeric characters. In your example string, "123454Mohsin", there is just one number: 123454. But there are 6 numeric characters.

Comment: Yeah exactly you got it einpoklum